# How to count the number of times a method is called for a mocked concrete class?

Tags: c#, moq

I have a mocked concrete class and when I try to count the number of times a method "x" is invoked in the class, I get an exception. I understand this is not a mocked interface and the method is not overridable. Is there any other way I can count?

I am mocking "RestClient" class of RestSharp. I could actually use the RestClient without mocking it. But I wont be able to tell how many times the "Execute" method of this class was called. I need this to test if the retry mechanism kicked in and tried to make the http call "x" number of times

```
Mock<RestClient> _mockRestClient = new Mock<RestClient>(mockHttpHandler, true);
//Act
            var res = _httpClient.ExecuteTaskWithPolicy(_mockRestClient.Object, _mockRestRequest.Object, policy);

            //Assert
            _mockRestClient.Verify(x => x.Execute(_mockRestRequest.Object), Times.Exactly(4));
```

```
Non-overridable members (here: RestClient.Execute) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.'
```

Comment: Can you share what method you're mocking, and how you're doing that?

Comment: "I get an exception" what exception? Typically it's a bad idea to try to mock something that's not an interface.

Comment: Exception-"Non-overridable members (here: RestClient.Execute) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.' I can avoid mocking RestClient and use it directly but i wont be able to count the number of times the method inside it was called

Comment: You can't use Moq to count how many times a method was invoked if you can't set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestSharp already deprecated `IRestClient` interface at v107. If you want to get API execute count, you can follow the [guideline](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/tree/108.0.1/docs/v107#mocking). For example, mix RestSharp and [MockHttp](https://github.com/richardszalay/mockhttp) to verify execute count:

```
[Test]
public async Task TestAsync()
{
    // arrange
    using var mockHttp = new MockHttpMessageHandler();
    var getFooMockedRequest = mockHttp
        .When("http://localhost/api/user/foo")
        .Respond("application/json", "{'name' : 'foo'}");
    var getBarMockedRequest = mockHttp
        .When("http://localhost/api/user/bar")
        .Respond("application/json", "{'name' : 'bar'}");

    using var client = new RestClient(
        new RestClientOptions("http://localhost/api")
        {
            ConfigureMessageHandler = _ => mockHttp
        });

    // act
    await client.GetAsync(new RestRequest("/user/foo"));
    await client.GetAsync(new RestRequest("/user/foo"));
    await client.GetAsync(new RestRequest("/user/foo"));

    await client.GetAsync(new RestRequest("/user/bar"));
    await client.GetAsync(new RestRequest("/user/bar"));

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(3, mockHttp.GetMatchCount(getFooMockedRequest));
    Assert.AreEqual(2, mockHttp.GetMatchCount(getBarMockedRequest));
}
```